# Вывод двух знаков в дробной части числа

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Kак правильно написать выражение - "только положительные числа и 2 знака после, если не ввели после запятой сотые, то записалось как .00"

Примеры:

- ввожу 1 = на выходе 1.00
- ввожу 2.3 = на выходе 2.30
- ввожу 3.11 = на выходе 3.11

Comment: `.toFixed(2)` ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pu49ef

Answer (score 1):

```
const currentNumber = Number(e.target.value);

if (currentNumber >= 0) {
  this.setState({
    amount: currentNumber.toPrecision(3)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе две задачи:

> только положительные числа и 2 знака после

1. проверка ввода (решается регулярным выражением )

> если не ввели после запятой сотые, то записалось как .00

2. форматирование введенного значения (решается дополнением регулярки, и методом `toFixed`)

Если соединить решение обеих задач в одной функции, получится следующее:

```js
function verify(input, transformNegative = false) {
  const inp = String(input).trim(), 
        re = /^([+\-]?)(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)$/; 
  const [match, sign, n] = inp.match(re) || []; 
  if (!match || (!transformNegative && sign === '-')) return null; 
  return (+n).toFixed(2); 
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
  console.clear(); 
  console.log(verify(target.value, true)); 
});
```

```html
<input>
```

В решении я предположил что отрицательные числа может быть необходимо приводить к положительным, поэтому знак числа достаю регуляркой (для простоты). Приведение сделано банально игнорированием знака, и включается вторым аргументом функции: если выключено, то ввод отрицательного числа воспринимается как ошибка ввода (с возвратом `null`).

Comment: старика можно поздравить с прошедшим праздником ? :)

Comment: @Leks, можно. А с каким? Неужели я пропустил День котонавтики?

Comment: насколько мне известно и в меру своей разумности понимаю старшее поколение основном положительно относиться к 7 ноября :))

Comment: @Leks, абсолютно положительно (положил на все календарные "праздники") - и особенно когда нахожусь на тематическом SO, отвечая на вопросы.

Comment: ясно удачи если что не так извините ... :)))

Answer (score 1):

Вот так ?

```js
let d = 2.3;

if( d > 0 ){
console.log( d.toFixed(2) )
}
```